# How to return a modified string after the request and loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops

I want to create autotag script for MMA app. For this I check article by RegExp to find first and last name and then push matches to array

```
var arr = [],
    s = "Самолет из Лондона уже час, как приземлился, а красавицы-чемпионки Уимблдона все никак не появляются в зале прилета. Мимо успели прошмыгнуть футболисты детской красноярской команды, бывший игрок волейбольной сборной России Роман Яковлев с сыном Дмитрием (пока выступающим на молодежном уровне), и даже актер Олег Тактаров – явно слегка удивленный наличием камер в аэропорту, но облегченно вздохнувший, когда понял, что пресса собралась не по его душу. Еще и Лиото Мачида был там",

 re = /([А-Я][А-Яа-я]+(?=\s[А-Яа-я])(?:\s[А-Я][А-Яа-я]+)+)/g,
    item;
var final_arr = [];
while (item = re.exec(s))
    arr.push(item[1]);
//arr = [ 'Роман Яковлев', 'Олег Тактаров', 'Лиото Мачида' ]
```

This maybe fighters or not. To check it, I'm sending a request to API. If this match I have 200 status and JSON, if not match 404:

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {


    var sss = encodeURIComponent(arr[i]);
    var options = {
                    url: 'https://------------------/get_fighter/'+sss,
                    method: 'GET',
                   }

    rp(options)
    .then(function (body) {
        var json = JSON.parse(body);
            var rus_name = json.rus_name;
            var vmeste_name = json.vmeste_name;
            console.log(vmeste_name)
            final_string = s.replace(rus_name, rus_name+'(#'+vmeste_name+')');
            console.log(final_string);
    })

    .catch(function (err) {
        // API call failed...
    });
```

And now I get a problem if there are more than one fighter in the db. How can I work with the last of iteration of final_string?

Comment: How do you mean last iteration? You would make 3 requests in this example right? Therefore make a global String-Array and put all the final strings in there. If final string contains more than one name, take the last and add it.

Comment: There is a DB with the fullnames of fighters. There is an article in which with the help of regexp I find possible fighters and collect them into an array. Then I pass this array through the loop through the API. In the article there can be mentioned not one person, but, for example, two as here. And it turns out that after the first iteration I had only one fighter processed, and after the second it was already two. I do not understand how I can get this final string after the loop is completed.

Comment: sorry, Phillip, There is a DB with the fullnames of fighters. There is an article in which with the help of regexp I find possible fighters and collect them into an array. Then I pass this array through the loop through the API. In the article there can be mentioned not one person, but, for example, two as here. And it turns out that after the first iteration I had only one fighter processed, and after the second it was already two. I do not understand how I can get this final string after the loop is completed

Comment: @sascha10000 There is a DB with the fullnames of fighters. There is an article in which with the help of regexp I find possible fighters and collect them into an array. Then I pass this array through the loop through the API. In the article there can be mentioned not one person, but, for example, two as here. And it turns out that after the first iteration I had only one fighter processed, and after the second it was already two. I do not understand how I can get this final string after the loop is completed.

Comment: @PhilippSander There is a DB with the fullnames of fighters. There is an article in which with the help of regexp I find possible fighters and collect them into an array. Then I pass this array through the loop through the API. In the article there can be mentioned not one person, but, for example, two as here. And it turns out that after the first iteration I had only one fighter processed, and after the second it was already two. I do not understand how I can get this final string after the loop is completed.

Comment: I would help if you add the input and an expected and an actual output

Comment: I also don't see where final_string is defined.

Comment: @PhilippSander final_string is defined after end of for loop

Comment: You are using final_string inside of the requests callback, why would you define it AFTER the for loop? You need some kind of a semaphore thing. A callback if all request are send and the response is processed. I will try to explain it inside an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var process_acquired_data = function(str){
    // do stuff with the final string
}

var processed_response_counter = 0; // added
var final_string = s; // added

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var sss = encodeURIComponent(arr[i]);
    var options = {
        url: 'https://------------------/get_fighter/'+sss,
        method: 'GET',
    }

    rp(options)
        .then(function (body) {
            var json = JSON.parse(body);
            var rus_name = json.rus_name;
            var vmeste_name = json.vmeste_name;
            console.log(vmeste_name)
            final_string = final_string.replace(rus_name, rus_name+'(#'+vmeste_name+')'); // changed
            console.log(final_string);

            processed_response_counter++;

            if(processed_response_counter == arr.length){
                process_acquired_data(final_string);
            }
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            // API call failed...
        });
}
```

What happened? First of I set final_string to the value of s. Then the .replace(...) will be done on final_string. Because everytime you call s.replce(...) you won't include the previously replaced values, because you are never resetting s.
On the other hand I've added a counter for all responses you got already. If I understand correct, you're done at the moment all responses came back... This means at the moment all responses came back you want to process the data. Therefore I have added a callback function (process_acquired_data) which will process the given string. In this case after all responses were made. Why didn't I use "i" as the counter? Quite simple, it may happen that a response is still pending while the loop has iterated (slow internet connection e.g.).

Keep in mind, when you are using callbacks the code is running asynchronously. This means you don't know WHEN (at which time of your code regarding the point in time) the callback will be processed. If you want to return the data. Use a Future (in JS it's called a promise I think and there is a library with that name).

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. I am created a callback.